# How to eliminate connecting line when plotting unwrapped function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to figure out how to eliminate the spurious "connecting line" that occurs when a function is "chopped" up so that it is plotted only in a single interval.  For example, suppose I have an angular function that extends from zero to 10 pi (or perhaps even larger) and I want to plot this function only in the range 0 to 2 pi.  I can use a modulo operation to fix the data, but if I plot it I get a line that connects from 2 pi back to zero, which I do not want to plot.  Here is some code that shows what I am talking about.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 1000)
y = t + np.sin(t)      
t2 = t%(2*np.pi)
plt.plot(t2, y)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot has a series of horizontal lines that I don't want (see image below).  I have done some research on this and have not found any simple way of dealing with this situation, but it seems like this would be somewhat common.

Any ideas?

[image]

By the way, I am dealing with a pretty large data set, so I can't very well do anything "by hand."

Comment: Are you asking about how to create a disjointed plot in general, or for this specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can use a `NaN` to insert a break into a point. In the particular case that you have shown, you can use `np.diff` to identify the discontinuities and set the `t2` value at those locations to `NaN` resulting in the desired breaks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 1000)
y = t + np.sin(t)
t2 = t % (2*np.pi)

# Compute the difference between successive t2 values
diffs = np.append(np.diff(t2), 0)

# Find the differences that are greater than pi
discont_indices = np.abs(diffs) > np.pi

# Set those t2 values to NaN
t2[discont_indices] = np.nan

plt.plot(t2, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks so much!

Comment: If case of measured data, you won't like to set some values to `NaN`. You need to insert rows with `NaN`s. You might even want to have connecting lines that wrap over. Insert pairs of rows with t values `0.` and `2.*np.pi`, respectively, and a common, interpolated y value, and a `NaN` row in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the same problem in a slightly different way: Create a x-mesh from 0 to 2*pi and then add an offset for `y` for plotting the five different curves. The key here is to exclude the last point of `t` using the index `[0:-1]` in order to avoid the continuation line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
t = (t%(2*np.pi))[0:-1]

for i in range(5):
    y = t+ np.sin(t) + i*2*np.pi
    plt.plot(t, y, 'b')
```

[image]